# Unable to call webservice from Java in flex application

Tags: java, web-services, maven, apache-axis

Hello I face some problem, I'm not able to to call webservice from java and send the result to flex side.

the process

- the user launches the application and lands on an authentication form
- The user enters login and password and submits the authentication form
- Submission call on java side a remoteservice checkUserCredetialFromLdap()
- inside this java method I try to call an external ldap webservice as shown below.
- The class responsible for ldap ws call is in custom jar (Maven dependencies)

  ```
  public User checkUserCredetialFromLdap(String identifiant, String password) throws EmmBusinessException, LdapServiceException{

      User myUser = null;
      User myCompleteUser = null;

       //initialization of webservice with the endpoint URL failed
      Axis1LdapWsAuth ws = new Axis1LdapWsAuth(Config.getProperties().getProperty("endpoint.url"));

      try{
          //authentication using webservice
          String csif_sessionID =ws.login(identifiant, password);
          ....
      }
      }catch(LdapServiceException lse)
      {
          EmmBusinessException emmB = new EmmBusinessException(lse,this,"","Unable to get User",Level.WARNING);
          log(emmB);
          throw (emmB);
      }
      catch (Exception t) {
          EmmBusinessException emmB = new EmmBusinessException(t,this,"","Unable to get User",Level.WARNING);
          log(emmB);
          throw (emmB);
      } finally {
          finish();
      }
      return myCompleteUser;
  }
  ```

I know it's possible to call webservice on flex side using RPC, but I don't want to do that, but for some reason I need to and have to call webservice from java side.

is't possible ? How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to:

- Develop a kind of proxy ldap webservice whose will do the bridge between flex app and your custom ldap authentication process
- Use HttpService from flex to send parameter to the proxy ldap
- Use proxy ldap to consume the checkUserCredetialFromLdap api with parameter get from flex